# while loop is not giving expected results

Tags: while-loop, python-3.6

i am learning python 3.6
while writing my script i come across a problem:

below are my codes

```
from sys import exit

print("Welcome to the official game designed by Prince Bhatia")
print("Copywrite @princebhatia")

def list1():
    loop = 5
    while loop == 5:

    print("Game starts here")
    list1 = ["Rahul", "Prince", "Sam", "Sonu"]
    print("which Player do you choose?")
    print("Now the game starts")
    name1 = input()

    if "Rahul" in name1 or "rahul" in name1:
        print("Rahul Enters the room1")
    elif "Prince" in name1 or "prince" in name1:
        print("Prince Enters the room2")
    elif "Sam" in name1 or "sam" in name1:
        print("Sam Enters the room3")
    elif "Sonu" in name1 or "sonu" in name1:
        print("Sonu Enters the room4")
    else:
        print("Please enter the valid name")
    loop = 6

list1()

print("""-------------------------------------""")
```

but problem is whenever i enter the defined names it works fine but when i enter the wrong name it stops, but what i want it should keep me asking "please enter valid name " until i enter valid name.
any suggestion. python 3.6

intend space is given here to give enter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your indentation is wrong.

To the problem: You are setting loop = 6 anyways, independent of whether you got a matching answer or not.

Here a slightly different suggestion:

```
print("Game starts here")
print("which Player do you choose?")
print("Now the game starts")

while True:

    name1 = input()

    if "Rahul" in name1 or "rahul" in name1:
        print("Rahul Enters the room1")
        break
    elif "Prince" in name1 or "prince" in name1:
        print("Prince Enters the room2")
        break
    elif "Sam" in name1 or "sam" in name1:
        print("Sam Enters the room3")
        break
    elif "Sonu" in name1 or "sonu" in name1:
        print("Sonu Enters the room4")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter the valid name")
```

This way we break the loop once we get a valid input, otherwise we keep looping indefinitely.

Comment: Sir, one question?  While true means every variable in while will be true, except else(please enter name again?

Comment: The True is like if you set a boolean flag = True and then do while (flag). Inside the loop you set flag = False  once you want to quit the loop. In my version break basically does this, it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: And no the True does not set every variable inside the loop to True in this scenario infact only tells the loop to keep running, while not doing anything else at all. The while loop just needs a boolean argument it does not matter if this is a  a comparison evaluating to True or just a boolean.

Comment: but is gives the same result , i just want to print please enter the valid name and until it enters the name , codes shouldnt stop while runnng your codes it prints
print("Game starts here")
    list1 = ["Rahul", "Prince", "Sam", "Sonu"]
    print("which Player do you choose?")
    print("Now the game starts")
    name1 = input()
but i want it to print only please enter valid name

Comment: You should read again about how loops work. Obviously everything INSIDE the loop will be repeated for as many times as you loop. If you don't want that put it outside the loop, I edit my answer accordingly but you really have to understand what the loop actually does.

Comment: Also you try to assign a list with names inside your function to the name of your function. This line does nothing, it just creates the said list in the local scope of your function/ loop. I guess you wanted to somehow use the list as a arguments for your function (which does not have a parameter). Let's not dive into that for now, maybe follow a Introductory Book or Course it seems like you are confusing quite a bit here.

Comment: Yes sir,i am learning while loop, i just started and understanding it more day by day, so today i thought lets see while loop inside function, i just started it..but now i am understanding it..it's different

Answer (score 1):

You can assign 5 to `loop` in the `else` and move up the assignment of 6 to the same variable:

```
from sys import exit

print("Welcome to the official game designed by Prince Bhatia")
print("Copywrite @princebhatia")

def list1():
    loop = 5
    while loop == 5:

    print("Game starts here")
    list1 = ["Rahul", "Prince", "Sam", "Sonu"]
    print("which Player do you choose?")
    print("Now the game starts")
    name1 = input()

    loop = 6

    if "Rahul" in name1 or "rahul" in name1:
        print("Rahul Enters the room1")
    elif "Prince" in name1 or "prince" in name1:
        print("Prince Enters the room2")
    elif "Sam" in name1 or "sam" in name1:
        print("Sam Enters the room3")
    elif "Sonu" in name1 or "sonu" in name1:
        print("Sonu Enters the room4")
    else:
        print("Please enter the valid name")
        loop = 5

list1()

print("""-------------------------------------""")
```

Anyway, it is a nice idea improving the name of this variable and the value. It would be better use a boolean variable here with a name like isInvalidName. So you `while` would be: `while isInvalidName:`

Comment: But sir.,what should i define to while Isinvalidname:?? Do i need to define the names? How can i take invalid input?

Comment: I mean you can rename `loop` variable to `isInvalidName`, and you can instead of assigning 5 to it, assigning `true`, and instead of assigning 6, you can assign `false`. It would make the code more readable

Comment: but is gives the same result , i just want to print please enter the valid name and until it enters the name , codes shouldnt stop while runnng your codes it prints
print("Game starts here")
    list1 = ["Rahul", "Prince", "Sam", "Sonu"]
    print("which Player do you choose?")
    print("Now the game starts")
    name1 = input()
but i want it to print only please enter valid name